# How do I detect if a SharePoint field is required in Power Apps?

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

This is one of those questions where it should be obvious, but I can't find the answer.

I am building a Power Apps Canvas application that is tied to a SharePoint Online list. I am using an Edit Form, so I have a Card for each field in my form. I want to make my labels red if the field is required. In the label within the card, how do I dynamically detect whether that SharePoint field is required or not?

**Update:** Parent.Required (Parent being the Card) SHOULD work, but always returns false. The following code works, but I have to manually insert the field name. In this example, "Location".

```
DataSourceInfo([@'Usage Log']),DataSourceInfo.Required,"Location")
```

How do I dynamically determine the field name? Parent.DataField returns "Location", but when I use it in the function:

```
DataSourceInfo([@'Usage Log']),DataSourceInfo.Required,Parent.DataField)
```

I get this error:

The Function 'DataSourceInfo' has some invalid arguments.

Argument 'Parent.DataField' is invalid, expected a text literal.

Answer (score 1):

Each field Card, in a Form control has a `Required` property.

[image]

This is an example of how you can take advantage of this property in a child control within a card:

1. Click on your control, for example, a label
2. Select a `Visible` property and use `Parent.Required` as a value:

[image]

Comment: I tried this. Parent.Required is always No.

Comment: If it's always No - try updating the SharePoint Data source in your Canvas app.

Comment: I did that. These same fields throw an error if I try to save with the field empty, so I know it's detecting required. Maybe I need to restart Power Apps.